# best way for managing uploaded files in my editor?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, ckeditor

I'm working on a social blog that has an editor built in JavaScript for creating a blog by a user. One of my biggest issues is uploading files and its limitations. Right now for auto-saving user posts, I store images uploaded simultaneously to the server. But the problem is when the user deletes images from the editor because:

- The number of requests might be too much (even when there are a lot)
- In Ckeditor I have a procedure for uploading, but there are not for deleting it from server (or at least I don't know how)
- and finally is that good idea for auto-saving (?)

My editor is a customized version of ckeditor5, and for uploading files, I use an uploadadapter like :

```
export default class UploadAdapter {
    constructor(loader, article) {
        this.loader = loader;
        this.article = article;
    }
    upload() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let image = new FormData();
            let url = '/articles/imageUpload';
            image.append('upload', this.loader.file);
            image.append('token', this.article.token);

            axios.post(url, image)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                    if (response.data.uploaded) {
                        resolve({
                            default: response.data.url,
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        reject(response.data.error.message);
                    }
                }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: 6 upvotes and 3 stars, seems like a popular topic. Grats. "_but the problem is when the user deleted images from the editor_" What would that problem be?

Comment: We miss a little info on your server side but I think you need a way to uniquely identify the image uploaded with a hash and a method on your server side to delete it

Comment: thank u for upvoting, and I try to clarify my problem @kerbholz

Comment: @kerbholz yes i think its a common problem, my app uses a different stack but same functionality ala Upload an image in the editor, but when the user deletes it i have an unneccessary upload happening because once the user inserts it it gets uploaded

Comment: @Badgy Actually, that's problem :))  And is session could be an option here? I mean everything saves in session and finally by uploading the last edition upload. Is it safe?

Comment: @davidonet - `hash_file('sha1', $pathtofile)`  to get a file hash is quite simple.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-file.php

Comment: Another solution would be to have a media library and let that handles the images, by doing that you avoid issues like re-uploading. If a user accidentally deletes an image they will have to re-upload the image which might cause confusion. There doesn't seem to be a reason to delete and image form the server through the editor, and a media manager section will probably be more useful.

Comment: You can see [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58503790/ckeditor-how-to-remove-image-files-in-server-when-canceled-posts/64649268#64649268) It may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the below to embed the images as base64 instead of uploading them

```
class UploadAdapter {
   constructor( loader ) {
      this.loader = loader;
   }

   upload() {
      return this.loader.file
            .then( file => new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
                  var myReader= new FileReader();
                  myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
                     resolve({ default: myReader.result });
                  }

                  myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            } ) );
   };
}
```

Comment: base64 is alternative but not the best practice since it will affect the server performance in the long run

Answer (score 1):

IMHO first you should define your goals, then search for the solution.

- Do you want your users to have a nice feature-rich file manager? It would allow them to choose from already uploaded images. One can work on preparing and uploading images, others would just choose them and paste them into the editor.
- Are you just willing to have a drag&drop solution and upload those images somewhere without wondering about the storage?
- Do you need to keep track changes over the edited content?
- Do you want to allow end-users to re-use already uploaded files?

Managing images removed from the content can be tricky depending on the needs. For example, if you want to keep track changes and allow users to re-use uploaded images in other posts - before removing any image from the storage you should check all posts and all versions if they do not contain this image anymore. OTOH if you don't care about versions and do not allow users to re-use images - then you can remove any image just after it's removed from the content.

Nowadays storage is cheap, so I wouldn't bother that much about keeping some extra images that are not used anymore. And what's more important - I wouldn't add the clean-up to the main flow. Rather than that - create a dedicated, repeated job for scanning the content and removing unused images. To make it more robust I would save the image usages in some kind of database. This way it would be much easier to perform the clean-up.

There are out-of-the-box paid solutions like [EasyImage](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-cloud-services/easy-image/) (upload, re-scale and optimize images to the CDN), or [CKFinder](https://ckeditor.com/ckfinder/) (fully-featured file manager).

Although, depending on your needs you may need to tune those solutions anyway. For example, if you have a file manager then maybe you would like to block deleting files if they are used anywhere. So additional work on some plugin might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

> Don't know this will help you or not. But i used to solve this remove
>   image issue like this.
>
> I used [summernote](https://summernote.org/) editor.

**Steps i followed when i inserting images with other contents:**

**Collected all the images from editor**

```
$images = $dom->getelementsbytagname('img');
```

**Here i receiving the images as base64. thats why i needed to decode them and store separately**

```
$imagePaths = [];
foreach($images as $k => $img){
        $data = $img->getattribute('src');
        $check_image = substr($data,0,10);
        if($check_image != "data:image"){
            continue;
        }
        list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
        list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
        $data = base64_decode($data);
        $image_name = time().$k.'.png';
        $path = public_path("/").ImagePaths::$BLOG_DETAILS_PICTURE.'/'.$image_name;
        file_put_contents($path, $data);
        $img->removeattribute('src');
        $img->setattribute('src', asset(ImagePaths::$BLOG_DETAILS_PICTURE.'/'.$image_name));
        $imagePaths[] = $path; // This path for store in DB
    }
```

**When i delete or update the content i just remove all the images which i received in `$imagePaths` array previously and stored.**

When i worked on this, i followed [this](https://www.kerneldev.com/2018/01/11/using-summernote-wysiwyg-editor-with-laravel/) documentation

[Here](https://codebunk.com/b/580265458/) i shared full controller script.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that you just need an extra hidden input which records all uploaded successfully images and do a little compare with the image`s urls in the editor after user posted the form, and then you will get the image list to be deleted.
I wish I had expressed my mean clearly.