# CKEditor How to remove image files in server when canceled posts

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, wysiwyg, web-development-server, ckeditor5

I'm using nodeJS(back-end), react(front-end), mongoDB. And I installed CKEditor5 for posting on board with many images.

It perfectly works uploading images on my server folder with `CKfinder`. But **If someone stop to post with images uploaded, useless images remain on my server folder.** And, delete uploaded images on the editor (like tab a delete key), still remain on server folder.

How can I delete images on my server folder when users delete images on editor or stop to post with images uploaded.